# Tomcat with Processing(" using java.awt library in linux X11 display error")

Tags: processing

I met a very annoying problem while I am trying to put a program integrated Processing on a tomcat server...I checked many solutions about this. Most of them is saying that the applet on the server side is so-called heavy weight component...But I can't shift them into client side cause I just want processing to make a picture and then send this to the client.

So I think I didn't call the applet display or some interactive operations..I don't know why I have this problem "using java.awt library in linux X11 display problem"..So if I change the tomcat setting as most of people said `-DJava.awt.headless=true`, it will get into another error..Both errors show that there is a problem in `Papplet.java` 244 lines in the source code of processing:

```
  static public final int MENU_SHORTCUT = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
```

Can somebody help me , I got stuck here like ages.......

**For complementary...If I change it as most of the saying on website..**

setting:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

After setting this, the new error mesage is as follows

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:387)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    de.fhg.iais.kd.tm.quote.casReadWrite.CasAnnotationCollector.finishProcessing(CasAnnotationCollector.java:72)
```